# Algorithm to find number of characters from where left and right have a match

Tags: algorithm

What could be the optimum solution to find the number of characters in a string from where left and right substring have all the characters of a string.

For example:

1. In string `fadooGfoo` have 1 such character `G` from where left and right both have `foo`.
2. In string `foofoo` there is no such character from where left and right both have `foo`.
3. In string `fooGLfoo` there are 2 such characters from where left and right both have `foo`.
4. In string `fooGFooF` there are 2 such characters from where left and right both have `foo`.

One approach, I can think of is to find match in all left and right for each character in string. This strategy can be further optimised.

Is there any better way to do the same?

Comment: What happens if there be more than one right answer, e.g. the condition could be met with 1 or three characters?

Comment: I don't understand your 4th example, and why are you looking for `foo`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen At least one should be there. so for example: `fooDfooGfoo, there are 2 such characters D and G.

Comment: @Yola in 4th example G and F's left have foo and right also have all characters of foo. (ooF is also counted as it have all characters of foo)

Comment: In `fooDfooGfoo` I'd say there are 5 such characters: `DfooG`

Comment: @user3386109 right

Comment: This is pretty unclear. Is the string whose characters should be left and right also an input to the algorithm?

Comment: So starting from the beginning of the string, you need to find a match for each character in "foo". And starting from the end, do the same. The exact details would depend on the programming language that you're using. But, for example, you could create a set `{f,o,o}` and then remove letters that match until the set is empty.

Comment: @user3386109: Imho, {f,o,o} is not a Set, since a set is unique about its elements.

Comment: @Henry we can assume that string is always foo

Comment: Ok then as suggested find left substring foo, find right substring foo (just reverse both string), and then answer is : everything in between. Find substring is linear : search 'f' from left then 'o' from current position then 'o' from current position, is linear.